# Find distinct combinations of four elements in an array that have a certain sum

Tags: java, array, sorting, combinatorics, hash-map

The task is: Given an array A of size N, find all combinations of four elements in the array whose sum is equal to a given value K.

The specific requirements are:

1. The combinations must be distinct
2. Each quadruple is separated by a delimiter "$", and must be printed in ascending order

Here are some test cases highlighting the points above:

- Case #1 -
  size of Array A: 5,
  K: 3,
  Array A: 0 0 2 1, 
  Answer: 0 0 1 2 $
- Case #2 - 
  size of Array A: 7,
  K: 23,
  Array A: 10 2 3 4 5 7 8,
  Answer: 2 3 8 10 $2 4 7 10 $3 5 7 8 $

---

I solved this task, but my solution involves a whole bunch of data structures...which may or may not be necessary. Additionally, at one point in time I generated all the possible combinations, which I think has a horrifying run-time of O(*n*<sup>4</sup>) :(

```
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Given an array A of size N, finds all combinations of four elements     in the array whose 
 * sum is equal to K.
 * @param args
 */

public class FindAllFourSumNumbers implements Comparable<FindAllFourSumNumbers> {

    private int first;
    private int second;
    private int third;
    private int fourth;
    private int[] m_arr;

    /**
     * A constructor function which stores four arguments in increasing order
     * @param args
     */
    public FindAllFourSumNumbers(int one, int two, int three, int four) {

        int[] temp = {one, two, three, four};

        Arrays.sort(temp);

        this.m_arr = temp;

        this.first = temp[0];
        this.second = temp[1];
        this.third = temp[2];
        this.fourth = temp[3];

    }

    /**
     * Getter function to get the array
     */
    public int[] getArr() {
        return this.m_arr;
    }

    /**
     * Making 2 objects equal so long as their m_arr contain the same elements
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {

        if (other == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (other == this) {
            return true;
        }

        if (!(other instanceof FindAllFourSumNumbers)) {
            return false;
        }

        FindAllFourSumNumbers otherObj = (FindAllFourSumNumbers) other;

        if (!Arrays.equals(this.getArr(), otherObj.getArr())) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    }

     /**
     * Overriding the hashCode method as well since equality was over-ridden
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Arrays.hashCode(this.m_arr);
    }

    /**
     * Compares two objects by looking at the first element of their m_arr
     */
    @Override
    public int compareTo(FindAllFourSumNumbers other) {

        int[] myArr = this.getArr();
        int[] otherArr = other.getArr();

        for (int i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {

            int current = myArr[i];
            int toCompare = otherArr[i];

            if (current > toCompare) {
                return 1;
            } else if (current < toCompare) {
                return -1;
            }

        }

        return 0;

     }

    /**
     * Allows for the printing of the pair
     * @param args
     */
    public String toString() {

         return this.first + " " + this.second + " " + this.third + " " + this.fourth + " " + "$";

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        //number of test cases
        int num = sc.nextInt();

        for (int t = 0; t < num; t++) {

            int n = sc.nextInt();
            int k = sc.nextInt();

            //prevents the need for rehashing
            HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<FindAllFourSumNumbers>> myMap = new HashMap<>(n);

            int[] storage = new int[n];

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

                storage[i] = sc.nextInt();

            }

            //generate all combinations of a + b + c + d and adding it to the hash map
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

                for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {

                    for (int l = j + 1; l < n; l++) {

                        for (int m = l + 1; m < n; m++) {

                            int a = storage[i];
                            int b = storage[j];
                            int c = storage[l];
                            int d = storage[m];

                            int sum = a + b + c + d;
                            FindAllFourSumNumbers myPair = new FindAllFourSumNumbers(a, b, c, d);

                            if (myMap.containsKey(sum)) {

                                ArrayList<FindAllFourSumNumbers> current = myMap.get(sum);

                                if (!current.contains(myPair)) {
                                    current.add(myPair);
                                }

                            } else {

                                ArrayList<FindAllFourSumNumbers> newList = new ArrayList<>(n);
                                newList.add(myPair);
                                myMap.put(sum, newList);

                            }
                        }
                    }

                } 

            }

            ArrayList<FindAllFourSumNumbers> toPrint = myMap.get(k);

            if (toPrint != null) {

                //so that everything is in order
                Collections.sort(toPrint);

                for (int i = 0; i < toPrint.size(); i++) {

                    FindAllFourSumNumbers current = toPrint.get(i);
                    System.out.print(current.toString());

                }

                System.out.println(" ");

            } else {

                System.out.println(-1);

            }

         }

        sc.close();

    }

}
```

Lengthy, yes, but it is complete, and I have commented it to make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for sharing the code.

You don't ask for certain things to look at so here is my general critic:

### formal issues

#### comments

Comments should always say **why** the code is like it is. Your comment mostly repeat what the code expresses itself.

Especially you have comments to explain variables like this:

```
    //number of test cases
    int num = sc.nextInt();
```

why not giving them better names instead?

```
  int numberOfTestCases = sc.nextInt();
```

You have a comment which logically forms a block inside your `main` method. You could extract that block to a method with a name derived from the comment:

```
 Map<> myMap= createHashMapFromAllCombinationsOf(a, b, c, d);
```

#### naming

Finding good names is the hardest part in software development. So always take extra time to carefully choose them.

**naming conventions**

It is good that you follow formal patterns of the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).

**identifiers with explaining comments**

When ever you feel you need a comment to explain an identifier name take another 5 minutes to find a better name that makes the comment obsolete.

**single letter names**

Avoid single letter names and abbreviations unless they are *very* common.

**No Verbs in class names**

classes are (kind of) pattern for *objects* So they should not have verbs in their names like `FindAllFourSumNumbers`. This would make a good method name, but not a class name. (would you agree with `MoveThingsToSomeOtherPlace` instead of `Vehicle`?)

You should have the usage of your identifiers in mind when looking for names. Therefore I'd suggest to rename the class to `SumOfNumbers`

### solution

#### duplicated feature

you store your data twice, in an array *and* in separate variables. Choose one and omit the other.

#### complexity

IMHO the solution requires O(n<sup>4</sup>) but your solution is O(n<sup>5</sup>) because of the (unneeded) `storage` array that you fill before the actual calculation.

You could reduce the complexity for some special cases when you limit the loops up to `k` since any tuple containing `k+x` has a sum bigger than `k`.

#### **know your tools**

The `if`/`else` in your loops clutters the code a bit. You could avoid the `if` by using the `Map`s `getOrDefault()` method:

```
ArrayList<FindAllFourSumNumbers> current = myMap.getOrDefault(sum, new ArrayList<>());
 if (!current.contains(myPair)) {
    current.add(myPair);
 }
 myMap.put(sum, newList);
```

And since you implemented `equals` and `hashcode` you could even leave the uniqueness (and the sorting) to the JVM:

```
 Collection<FindAllFourSumNumbers> current = myMap.getOrDefault(sum, new TreeSet<>());
 current.add(myPair);
 myMap.put(sum, newList);
```

---

> 1) does the fact that I stored it again in separate variables add to any costs?  – umop apisdn

The obvious answer is: yes, since it uses extra memory.

The not so obvious answer is: I don't know (and don't care) since the JVM may (or may not) do some optimization to deal with that.

The point is: it confuses the reader.

---

> I did that because I thought it might help with clarity since I won't have to keep doing storage[0], storage[1] etc. – umop apisdn

This reasoning is perfectly valid.

But on the other hand you only use the distinct variables in the `toString()` method. This could also be written this way:

```
public String toString() {  
  return Arrays.toString(m_array);  // add "[]" around the values
}
```

Then the distinct variables would be obsolete.

---

> 2) can you give more hints on how to work on the calculations directly without storing into an array? – umop apisdn

You mean something like you're doing here?

> ```
>  int sum = a + b + c + d;
> ```

---

> Also, how did you get O(n^5) for my solution...shouldn't it be O(n^4 + n + n choose 4) ~ O(n^4) ? thanks! – umop apisdn

Here I might be wrong, because only *nested* loops contribute exponents to the complexity.

But you definitely do not need the `storage` array and the loop to fill it.

ie.: if your loop variables are

```
i = 0;
j = 3;
l = 5;
m = 7;
```

what are the values you get in `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`?

And this is the best advice to improve performance I've ever ben given:

> The fastest way to do something is not to do it.

Comment: thanks a lot for providing comprehensive comments on both formatting and the solution itself, really appreciate it. However,  I am still curious about some things: 1) does the fact that I stored it again in separate variables add to any costs? I did that because I thought it might help with clarity since I won't have to keep doing storage[0], storage[1] etc. 2) can you give more hints on how to work on the calculations directly without storing into an array? Also, how did you get O(n^5) for my solution...shouldn't it be O(n^4 + n + n choose 4) ~ O(n^4) ? thanks!

Comment: @umopapisdn just to make sure you recognized the update...